# How to communicate between iOS and Android for a game

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi

I read several posts but either they don't answer my question or are too old.
Let say I want to developp a Card Game app for which I need the devices to communicate between them **instantly**. Also I need only a **local connection**. People would play in the same room.

What are then the option to make all those devices (iOS,Android and tablet/smartphone) together?
WIFI, Bluetooth, other,...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everyone is on WiFi, then use sockets since it is the simplest. Bluetooth requires close proximity, so not ideal.

You will have two areas to solve:

1) Finding other players on the network

For this I would use UDP messages. Have your app open a UDP socket on a well known port and register it on the run loop. When looking for other players, and possibly regularly on a timer, have your app send out a UDP AnybodyOutThere type message to the network broadcast address and your game port. In this message encode the player information and anything else you want to use.

You could also create a multicast group if you wish for your app and send to that.

When your app receives a UDP AnybodyOutThere message, process it and then send an ImHere type message directly to the sender and record their IP address.

When your app receives a UDP ImHere type message, add the player to your internal list of players and record their IP address.

Through this all your devices will quickly build up an understanding of who is on the game.

2) Communicating between the devices during game play.

For reliability, you might want to use TCP/IP sockets for this part. Have your app open a TCP listen socket on a well known port (different from your UDP port). You can actually use any port, as long as you include the port in the UDP discovery messages from step 1).

To request players join a game you are hosting on one device, have that device send an invite over UDP directly to the players selected. If they choose to join, have their device connect using a TCP socket to the hosting device on the port that device is listening on. You now have any players who join reliably connected to your hosting device.

The rest is down to you creating a protocol to use to manage the interactions needed for the game.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The point is that with WIFI, am I sure that communication will be instantely? Without any delay. I mean, if a player press a button on his/her smartphone, I need to have an action on all the other devices instantely, max few ms for example. I thought WIFI might not be 100% reliable for this.

Comment: @yoan26 If you use TCP, then the messaging is reliable as long as you all stay connected. You can detect disconnects and reconnect. Speed will depend on your WiFi, but you are talking about Mbps which is way more than you need.

Comment: Thank you for the information! So it seems that I should go for WIFI with socket for my multi OS app.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using sockets. You can open a TCP socket on one device and other devices can listen to this socket. Then you can use JSON to send messages from one device to another. For sockets you can use the native sockets in iOS and Android or you can look for a library like Socket.IO